# Ambiguous call to overloaded function - log vs. ptrdiff_t

Tags: c++, matlab, type-conversion, mex, ambiguous

I have received a code line that's like
`entr -= normed_eigval * log(normed_eigval) / log(dim);`

While `normed_eigval` stems from `complexArray*`, I know that `dim` is of type `ptrdiff_t`. When I try to compile the code using the MEX interface of MATLAB and Visual Studio 10 as compiler, I receive an error:

```
C2668: ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

telling me that `log` could either be `long double`, `float` or `double`.

I am using a 64-bit Windows machine. Can I solve this problem using a type cast? If yes, which type should I choose? I figure there's some possible problems under 64-bit Windows if `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` are to be transformed into standard integer types...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose whichever one agrees with `normed_eigval` because that determines the numeric precision you're working with. You will be converting the `ptrdiff_t` integer into a floating-point value, then taking its logarithm.

Likely you can precompute the inverse of the logarithm, if you need it to go faster.

Comment: Thank you. Converting the ptrdiff_t integer into a double did the trick.